# PHP outputs question marks

Tags: php

I'm deploying an application on a server in Japan. The application is a product which my company is selling, and it's been successfully installed on many other servers without such problems.
The application is written in PHP/CodeIgniter, and the same package was successfully tested on other servers.

The problem is- the application only shows some question marks (and then it dies with an error, that a certain class is not found, although the same code works on other server). Some application files are encoded with Zend Guard- Zend Optimizer is available on both servers.
What I have tried/found out:
1) Major PHP version on both servers is the same- 5.2.x

2) Zend Optimizer versions are the same- 3.3.9

3) The question marks are in fact question marks- piped the output to file with wget and opened it in HEX editor- the file mostly contains 3F, with some random HEX symbols between:

```
0000000: 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f01 3f3f 3f3f  ???????????.????
0000010: 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 203f 3f3f 3f3f  ?????????? ?????
0000020: 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f  ????????????????
0000030: 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f  ????????????????
0000040: 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f  ????????????????
0000050: 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f  ????????????????
0000060: 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f  ????????????????
0000070: 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f  ????????????????
0000080: 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f  ????????????????
0000090: 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f  ????????????????
00000a0: 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f  ????????????????
00000b0: 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f  ????????????????
00000c0: 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f  ????????????????
00000d0: 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f  ????????????????
00000e0: 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f  ????????????????
00000f0: 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f  ????????????????
0000100: 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f  ????????????????
0000110: 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f  ????????????????
0000120: 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f  ????????????????
0000130: 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f 3f3f  ????????????????
```

4) Application dies at a point, where no output should have been sent yet.

5) I suspect, that the problem is related to PHP settings- so far, I have tried setting default_charset to 'utf-8' in php.ini, but that does not change anything.

6) Expected output to the point where application crashes should be nothing- no output at all. Instead, I get the output above (it continues on in that manner).

EDIT:
I guess I am getting somewhere- the problem is with Zend Optimizer. Replacing the encoded files helped, and the output is as expected. This creates another problem- how to tell what's wrong with Zend Optimizer? The encoded files were tested on different server with the same version of Zend Optimizer, and they run fine. PHP versions are 5.2.14 on the server which works, vs 5.2.13 on the server where the encoded files do not work.

Comment: I don't know the answer, to-be-sure.  But you might want to try asking over at http://serverfault.com as well.

Comment: 1) anything suspicious in http headers? 2) default web server encoding issues?

Comment: Is this input that is being sent out? Garbage in, garbage out. You really haven't given enough information to think about the issue, all we know for sure is that you have mysterycode X that is doing something odd, and we know nothing about expected output, what the code is, or otherwise.

Comment: etranger: Nothing suspicios in headers- default web server encoding is set to utf-8, and Apache sends the correct Content-Type header- text/html; charset=utf-8
I have edited my question with clarification on what is expected output- garbage is not expected.

Comment: question marks without spaces, without punctuation, without latin characters? What language it was in?

Comment: Are you sure Zend Guard/Optimizer is actually working? Like, the `phpinfo()` output is all good, and testing an encoded dummy file vs unencoded dummy file produces the same output?

Comment: Execute the php scripts without going through your webserver and run a profiler on the code.

Comment: user257493, how's that's going to help? The same installation package ran smoothly on other server.

Comment: Question marks sometimes comes with incorrect charset connection with MySQL database. Is the app in question involve MySQL?

Comment: user257493, will try, but that's not trivial. I have the same package running on other server, so I'll try that as last resort.
Col. Shrapnel- english. But that does not matter, as the output to that point should be nothing.
Spencer Hakim- it's good in phpinfo(); but I'll try to encode a dummy file and test it.

Comment: timdream- it does, but these question marks do not come from database- at that point there should not be any output at all.

Comment: @fest: Any luck with the dummy file?

Comment: @Spencer: I updated my question- see the last paragraph.
Some googling revealed that similar output is seen when Zend Optimizer is not loaded properly, but I don't see any errors in Apache error_log about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php.ini:

```
zend_optimizer.enable_loader=0
```

The error was cryptic enough though...

Answer (score 1):

Go to the first line of the file in question and add `echo 'flag1';`. Go to the first `include()` and add `echo 'flag2';` after it. Continue for every `include()` and one more at the end of the file. This will tell you where the question marks are starting and you can move them around until you find the exact source.

If this process leads you into the CodeIgniter libraries, then it could be a bug in their code and you'd have to bring it up with them.

Comment: Thanks for this- I was reluctant to do this tedious task, but this got me to the culprit of the problem- Zend optimizer.